# uv4l not detecting camera

Tags: camera, uv4l

I'm trying to use uv4l to stream camera over WebRTC, using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, running latest Raspberry Pi OS 32 bits.
The camera is the "Camera Module 3 NoIR Wide".

Whenever the service starts, or if I try to run uv4l manually like with this:

```
sudo uv4l -nopreview —auto-video_nr —driver raspicam —encoding mjpeg —width 640 —height 480 —framerate 20 —server-option '--port=9090' —server-option '--max-queued-connections=30' —server-option '--max-streams=25' —server-option '--max-threads=29'
```

I get an error " [core] No device detected".

Here's an excerpt from: "journalctl -u uv4l_raspicam.service"

```
Feb 03 21:10:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started uv4l_raspicam.service - UV4L Raspicam.
Feb 03 21:10:54 raspberrypi uv4l[515]: <notice> [core] Trying to loading driver 'raspicam' from built-in drivers...
Feb 03 21:10:54 raspberrypi uv4l[515]: <notice> [core] Loading driver 'raspicam' from external plug-in's...
Feb 03 21:10:54 raspberrypi uv4l[515]: <warning> [core] libbcm_host.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Feb 03 21:10:54 raspberrypi uv4l[515]: <alert> [core] No device detected
```

Now in raspi-config, even after update, I don't have any option to enable the camera.

I can however capture from the camera using rpicam-still and rpicam-vid.

"vcgencmd get_camera" outputs:

```
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

I've tried various answers to similar questions I found, without success.

I've also try on a Raspberry Pi 4 without more success...